# Invoke tinyMCE commands in ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am trying to use tinyMCE in a ruby on rails application. This is my initialization code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinyMCE.init({
                // General options
                // script_url: '/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
                mode : "textareas",
                theme : "advanced",
                plugins : "layer,inlinepopups",
                relative_urls : false, 
                theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "tablecontrols",
                table_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3",
                table_cell_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Cell=tableCel1",
                table_row_styles : "Header 1=header1;Header 2=header2;Header 3=header3;Table Row=tableRow1",
                table_cell_limit : 100,
                table_row_limit : 5,
                table_col_limit : 5,
```

The initialization is working fine. Now, I am not using the tinyMCE toolbar, and instead have my own links, which when clicked, the tinyMCE functions for formatting text, inserting image, etc. should be invoked.

For instance, I have used tinyMCE table plugin, and need to insert table into the textarea when my page loads. This is what I tried:

```
editor = tinyMCE.get('editor');
editor.mceInsertTable();
```

But its not working. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mceInsertTable is an execCommand. You will need to call the following

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertTable');
```

Comment: That definitely worked. Now, after I insert a table, I need to be able to merge/split cells, do things with table. I was told that when the table plugin correctly loads, a small marker shows when you select cells in the table, but I don't see anything. Can you help me on how I can change the way the table looks? Thanks.

Comment: i am sorry, but i am not very familiar with the table plugin

Comment: I actually figured it out. I used the contextmenu plugin, which would show table-related menu, so i can now modify a table. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you just use the TinyMCE JavaScript API:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.hide();
```

Comment: I can activate tinyMCE, I can get the toolbar to show, and insert images, videos, using the toolbar buttons too. But the thing is that I don't want that, I have my own button, and want to invoke an insert table, say, when i press a button, or insert an image, when i click another button. How can i achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: rookieRailer: Do you know JavaScript? Add a click event listener on your button and call tinyMCE's JavaScript api like the above. You can do anything TinyMCE buttons can do with JavaScript. TinyMCE's buttons are just calling the same JavaScript API's that you would.

Comment: yes i do. i am using jQuery. I have edited my post a little. Please see the changes, maybe you can help me build up on this. Thanks.